# Inline listings crash when argument ends in "Error" under the Python language

Tags: listings

Well, this is honestly the strangest thing I've ever seen concerning LaTeX.

A friend of mine encountered what I can only describe as a bug in `listings`; can it be resolved?

See the minimal example below with errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstMakeShortInline[language=Python]"

\begin{document}
"ThisIsAFakeError".
"ThisIsAFakeErro".
\end{document}
```

### Error message:

```
ERROR: Missing } inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                }
l.8 "ThisIsAFakeError".

--- HELP ---
TeX has become confused. The position indicated by the error locator
is probably beyond the point where the incorrect input is.


ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\lst@eaten ->".

l.8 "ThisIsAFakeError".

--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.
```

Comment: `"Er"` is bad as well

Comment: This probably has to do with the Python language definition, which uses `"` as string delimiter. Tell your friend that the choice of `"` as a shorthand for inline Python code is a bad one; a backtick, for instance, would be preferable.

Comment: @Jubobs The poor choice lies with me, unfortunately. A backtick makes much more sense, especially within the context of other plain-text markup languages like Markdown.  I'll have to remember that for next time. :)

Comment: I'm sure we could find _something_ stranger than this:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing `"Ej"` (which works) with `"Er"` (which doesn't) `\tracingall` shows it goes wrong here

```
\lst@IfNextChars@@ #1#2\relax #3->\def \lst@tofind {#2}\lst@lAddTo \lst@eaten {
#3}\ifx #1#3\ifx \lst@tofind \@empty \let \lst@next \@tempa \else \let \lst@nex
t \lst@IfNextChars@ \fi \expandafter \lst@next \else \expandafter \@tempb \fi 
#1<-"
#2<-""
#3<-"
```

where `"` is being used as a delimiting token and as the token being tested...

A workaround is to use something else eg `^`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstMakeShortInline[language=Python]^

\begin{document}
^ThisIsAFakeError^.
^ThisIsAFakeErro^.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the issue, but can you explain what exactly is tripping up if you get the time? My TeX-fu yet leaves much to be desired…

Comment: @SeanAllred Possibly, but first drive home, eat etc. Meanwhile you can read http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/ (Hot off the press today)

Answer (score 2):

If "your friend" (yeah right! `:p`) looks up how the `Python` language is defined by `listings` in the file [lstdvrs.dtx](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx), "s/he" will see that the `"` character is defined as a string delimiter for that language:

```
morestring=[b]",%
```

No wonder, then, that TeX gets confused if "your friend" tries to also define that character as a shorthand for inline Python code. A character can't act both as a shorthand for inline code and as a delimiter, because `listings` has no way of knowing which function a given occurence of that character is supposed to fulfill.

You should tell "your friend" to choose a character that is less likely to occur in Python code, such as a backtick. For the specifics of the error, see David's answer.

Comment: All the `"your friend"`s made me smile :) but it really is a friend of mine this time.  That actually makes a lot of sense, and gives a lot of traction to the `` ` `` suggestion (since `` ` `` isn't used in many languages at all).

Comment: @SeanAllred I was just teasing you `:)`

Comment: @SeanAllred For information, if you want to insert a backtick in a TeX.SE comment, you need to escape it with a backslash: \`.

Comment: The idea was to get <pre>`</pre>, but thanks :)

Comment: @SeanAllred In that case, *backtick backslash backtick backtick* gives you what you want: `\``.

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that!? `\`` Thanks!